# background-cover

Tags: html, css

I am using a image like background for my web site

I put this to cover all page with the image

```
body.questionary{
    background: url("../img/ques.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

my image is a jpg the dimension is 703x883  and the size is 258KB

the problem is that when I see the page this image is very big, like a zoom , I dont see the image complety I only the top of it.

any idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you page is very tall, the `background-size:cover` will make the background image to scale so that it fills the whole `body`.

---

if you want it to fill the viewport only, then you will need to add inside another element (*not body*) and style that

```
<body>
   <div id="background"></div>
...
</body>
```

and

```
#background{
   position:fixed;
   z-index:0;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background: url("../img/ques.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I try your solution but a have the same problem

Comment: @user852610, it should not zoom.. can you post a jsfiddle with the code?

Comment: @user852610 if you want to see the whole image, use `contain` instead of `cover`. But that means that some areas of the background might not be filled by the background image..

Comment: thanks again @Gaby aka G. Petrioli but I want to see whole image and fill all the background

Comment: @user you will need javascript for this .. it is not possible with pure CSS to scale both up and down in order to fit. With `cover` which scales-up in order to fill the container, you could use a smaller image (*in dimensions*) but that would degrade quality for big screens..

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size:100% 100%;`

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmwPc/2/)

the values `contain` and `cover` maintain aspect ratio as defined by the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-background-size)

> ‘contain’ Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio
> (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height
> can fit inside the background positioning area.
>
> ‘cover’ Scale the
> image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the
> smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely
> cover the background positioning area.

Comment: I was getting the impression @user852610 wanted it to fill the space (assuming that meant breaking ratio)

Comment: I think the OP wants the image to scale up or down just enough so that it fills the whole page (*proportionally and as much image as possible*)